# "airmon-ng start wlan0" will not create mon0

Tags: wireless-networking, network-interface, aircrack-ng

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a Realtek RTL8187SE Driver, RTL8180/RTL8185 chipset with aircrack-ng 1.1 and every time i enter "airmon-ng start wlan0". It says "monitor mode enabled" instead of "monitor mode enabled on mon0". I checked ifconfig to see if it made another interface, but all I got was "wlan0", "lo", and "eth0". How can I fix this?

Comment: You should be able to run the utilities with wlan0 rather than mon0 if it didn't create mon0

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your chipset, driver, kernel and airmon-ng version, which would have made it easier to help you.

Not all drivers create mon0 for monitor mode, some enable it on the original interface (wlan0 in your case). Run `airmon-ng check` to check the status.
To confirm that your card is in monitor mode, run the command `iwconfig`. You can then confirm the mode is “monitor” and the interface name.

You could also run `airmon-ng check kill`, which will cause all processes that use the interface to exit.

> For the mac80211 drivers, the monitor mode interface is typically “mon0”. For ieee80211 madwifi-ng drivers, it is typically “ath0”. For other drivers, the interface name may vary.

[Source](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aireplay-ng)

To learn more about the difference of the drivers, read [here](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_drivers)

Comment: I upgraded to Aircrack-ng 1.2 beta 2 and mon0 was created.